# Integral of a velocity profile?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation

Part of my fluid mechanics homework asks me to solve:

$${\partial u\over \partial x} = 0$$

Which represents how the velocity profile, ***u***, changes in the ***x***. I'm not sure whether you can integrate partial derivatives but my intuition says that you just integrate and get:

$$u=C$$

Is this logic correct?

Comment: Is $u$ the same as $\mathbf{u}$?

Comment: yes. ***u*** is the velocity profile in the x direction.

Comment: The answer is $\int u_x\,\mathrm{d}x=f(t)$ for $f$ some function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity u could be a a function of *time* AND *space* in general. From the first relation mentioned in the problem, all you can infer is that velocity does *not* depend on space. All remains would be its *time-dependency*. You can also show all this in partial-derivative notation.